# Iterate through list, add list item id from list item text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

I wish to find an easy jQuery solution to iterate through a list's child selectors, in this instance, the ul > li span span child selectors, find the text, copy the text as the list item ID, all while removing the whitespace and replacing with underscore if there are any (for instance, in the example below, HR Area would become HR_Area then get added as the list item ID as li id="HR_Area").

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="/"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item">Staff</span></span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="directory.asp">Directory</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="/"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item">HR Area</span></span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="vacation.asp">Manage Vacation Time</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Your html markup is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I did change that second child selector to include the spans

Comment: You want to do for span only or anchor also?

Comment: Just wanted to get the ul > li >a>  span > span text and place it as the ul > li  ID (that make sense? hope it does :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select only the immediate li inside #menu.
I hope this is what you expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu>li .menu-item").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").attr("id", $(this).text().split(' ').join('_'));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item">Staff</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="directory.asp">Directory</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/">
      <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item">HR Area</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="vacation.asp">Manage Vacation Time</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Roshan, both methods work but yours seems to use less code, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the immediate child which is an li.
Then access the span and replace the spaces with underscore and set the id accordingly.

```
// Iterate over the immediate li elements for the ul

$('#menu > li').each(function(elem) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // Access the span element
    var $span = $('.menu-item', $this),
        spanText = $span.text(),
        // Replace space with underscore
        replacedText = spanText.split(' ').join('_');

    //  Set the id of for the li element
    $this.attr('id', replacedText);

});

$('#menu > li').each(function(elem) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpbsuL0d/)**

Comment: Looks great! one question, for instance, (and i know it wasn't in the original post's code) the nested unordered lists (#menu > li > ul > li) might have the same span classes, how to avoid picking up those as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menu").find("li").each(function(){
  $(this).find("span").each(function(){
    var txt = $(this).html();
    txt = txt.replace(" ","_");
    $(this).closest("li").attr("ID",txt);
  });
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="/"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item">Staff</span></span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="directory.asp">Directory</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="/"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item">HR Area</span></span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="vacation.asp">Manage Vacation Time</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```